# Extract common path from a collection of grouped file paths?

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching, directory

I have a question related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem, my source collection contains a list of file paths that doesn't always share a common path (outside of the C:\ drive sometimes) ex:

Source collection :

```
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\a.txt
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\b.txt
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\Dev\c.txt
C:\Test2\Random\Data\a.txt
C:\Test2\Random\b.txt
C:\Test2\c.txt
D:\Data\a.txt
```

Output should be a collection :

```
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\
C:\Test2\
D:\Data\
```

How to find the common path of each "group" of file paths ? I've found many solutions here but it is always with a collection of file paths sharing at least one common directory which is not the case here.

Comment: Why wouldn't `"C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\"` be part of the Output?

Comment: Why not C:\ and D:\ ?

Comment: @maccettura because the common folder for the first 3 paths is C:\Test\Root\Common\Data

Comment: @Valerii I need to group them by the lowest common folder not drive letter :)

Comment: @Coloris if you want to group by "lowest common folder", then `"C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\"` should be an output.  Your are not being clear at all.

Comment: @maccettura sorry if it's not clear, for me the first 3 paths are quite the same :
`C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\a.txt
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\b.txt
C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\Home\Dev\c.txt
`
The lowest common folder should be C:\Test\Root\Common\Data\ because a.txt is not part of Home

Comment: @Coloris ok so why are you arbitrarily choosing the first 3?

Comment: Because I consider them to be part of the same group so I want to find the  common folder for those 3 first, then jump to the second group which is C:\Test2\ etc... group might not be the best word to describe that.

Comment: @Coloris I would recommend coming up with _actual_ requirements.  You will likely find more help if you at least know what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure that I understand problem correctly...

I hope this will work.

```
    public List<string> ExtractCommonPaths(List<string> paths)
    {
        var separatedImput = paths
            .Select(path => path.Split(new [] {":\\", "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .Select(path => path.Take(path.Length - 1).ToList());
        return separatedImput.GroupBy(path => path[0] + ":\\" + path[1])
            .Select(g =>
            {
                var commonPath = g.Key;
                var commpoPathLength = 2;
                for (;;)
                {
                    var exit = false;
                    var pathItem = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var path in g)
                    {
                        if (path.Count <= commpoPathLength)
                        {
                            exit = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (pathItem == string.Empty)
                            pathItem = path[commpoPathLength];
                        else
                        {
                            if (pathItem != path[commpoPathLength])
                            {
                                exit = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (exit)
                        break;
                    commonPath += "\\" + pathItem;
                    commpoPathLength++;
                }

                return commonPath;
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Valerii, it's almost perfect, just that if there is only a single instance of a filepath it returns the complete filename D:\Data\a.txt instead of just D:\Data

Comment: I've fixed my solution

Comment: Thanks, gonna dig into your code to understand the logic :)

Comment: This throws on the `GroupBy` line if a path contains only 1 'segment', such as `C:\1.txt` or `C:\Temp`

Comment: @Cocowalla Yes. It looks like additional check should be added.

Answer (score 0):

I have something if you want to look for the directories inside some location.
To this method i have every of directories from some (C:\Files1) example location.

If you want to get only main directories from this list:

```
public List<DirectoryInfo> ExtractDirectoriesCommonPaths(List<DirectoryInfo> directories, string location)
    {
        var result = new List<DirectoryInfo>() { };
        directories.ForEach(directory =>
        {
            var otherDirectories = directories.Where(d => d.FullName != directory.FullName);
            var anyDirectoryWithThisSamePath = otherDirectories.Where(x => directory.FullName.Contains(x.FullName) && x.FullName.Length < directory.FullName.Length);
            if (anyDirectoryWithThisSamePath.Any())
            {
                result.Add(anyDirectoryWithThisSamePath.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        });

        return result.Where(x => x.FullName != location && x.FullName.Length > location.Length).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Input:

```
C:\Files1\test_announcements
C:\Files1\Parent
C:\Files1\test_announcements\test_announcements_archive
C:\Files1\Parent\child
C:\Files1\Parent\child2
C:\Files1\Parent\child\subchild
C:\Files1\test_announcements
C:\Files1\Parent
```

Output:

```
C:\Files1\test_announcements
C:\Files1\Parent
```